# Qt: Storing a custom object in a collection by value

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

Let's say I have this class:

```
class Bear
{
public:
    Bear ();
    Bear (Bear &other);

    // ... methods

private:
    BearInfo* m_pInfo;
};
```

Can I store `Bear` objects in a `QList<Bear>` **by value**?  According to the documentation:

> Internally, `QList<T>` is represented as an array of pointers to items of type `T`. If `T` is itself a 
>   pointer type or a basic type that is no larger than a pointer, or if `T` is one of Qt's shared 
>   classes, then `QList<T>` stores the items directly in the pointer array.

While my class just consists of a pointer, it is neither a *pointer type* nor a *basic type*, so it seems to me that the `QList` will store pointers (`Bear*`), which is not what I want. And since the `BearInfo` structure must be mutable, I cannot derive `Bear` from `QSharedDataPointer`.

Any suggestions how I can enable this class to be stored **by value** in the Qt collections?

Comment: What does "basic type" even mean in this context? POD?

Comment: I assume int, char, long, etc.

Comment: Jen, your correct about the basic type. unless you want to & your classes, use an stl container that can size to the full data structure in ram efficiently. Qt, loves pointers ;)

Comment: Well, in finding a correct answer, assuming only goes so far. ;-] If it means trivially copyable, then your class should fit the criteria of "*a basic type that is no larger than a pointer*"; if it means POD, then your class doesn't. So it seems to me the answer to my question is also the answer to yours -- do the Qt docs ever explicitly define "basic type"?

Comment: Good point. The QML documentation uses the term *basic type* to mean any of the primitives as well as some Qt-provided types such as QString, QDate, QFont, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [QVector](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qvector.html), the Qt Documentation states this:

QList, QLinkedList, and QVarLengthArray provide similar functionality. Here's an overview:

- For most purposes, QList is the right class to use. Operations like prepend() and insert() are usually faster than with QVector because of the way QList stores its items in memory (see Algorithmic Complexity for details), and its index-based API is more convenient than QLinkedList's iterator-based API. It also expands to less code in your executable.
- If you need a real linked list, with guarantees of constant time insertions in the middle of the list and iterators to items rather than indexes, use QLinkedList.
- **If you want the items to occupy adjacent memory positions, or if your items are larger than a pointer and you want to avoid the overhead of allocating them on the heap individually at insertion time, then use QVector.**
- If you want a low-level variable-size array, QVarLengthArray may be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

just use an stl container, it's available everywhere, even in QT.

its what i do. :)

Comment: Thought about that, but I like the Qt classes for their cleaner syntax and better performance characteristics.

Comment: Yea, i know Qt's syntax is very elegant. But they are stengy when it comes to allocation, whereas an stl container, is not.

Comment: @ildjarn: There are some optimizations in Qt concerning shallow/deep copying and list insertions ... but unfortunately, no cite :(

Answer (score 2):

> Can I store Bear objects in a
>   `QList<Bear>` by value?

**No.**  Your quote from the documentation was correct:  Internally, `QList<T>` stores pointers to items of type `T`.

**Instead, use `QVector`, which stores objects by value of type larger than a pointer (that is its purpose).**

A similar issue with items in `QList<>` are issues with containment by `QVariant`, which holds any primitive type, or some other small types (like `QDate`).  So, you get value semantics in `QVariant` only if your value fits into a primitive or a pointer.

Full containment would be achieved if you had a container of objects like `QPointer` or `QSharedPointer` instances, which logically share-and-track references to (reference counted) objects, etc.

Unlike STL (with value semantics), Qt leans on containers of "pointers-to-items" because of problems when those items are polymorphic (different sizes in derived classes).  (This is quite common in object oriented systems, which is why Qt defaults to pointer semantics.)

For example, in Qt, `QList<Bear>` is fine (implemented as a container of pointers-to-`Bear` instances), but the `std::list<Bear>` would be problematic when all Bear instances are not the same size (for example, if `KodiakBear` and `BlackBear` derived from `Bear`, and you added those derived instances to the `std::list<Bear>` class).  In that case, the derived state would be "stripped" through value semantics.